# Apache Camel CXF response 202 instead of 200

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-camel, interceptor

I am using Apache Camel CXF to integrate a SOAP WebService. Everything works fine but I have noticed that my response is coming back as HTTP 202 instead of 200. I am kinda concerned because I know many people hardcode things like `if(httpCode == 200) {...}` and this could break the current service.

I have tried using different interceptors to override the HTTP code from 202 to 200, but no luck. Also, 202 means `Accepted` which means the request is in process but not finished. 200 means `OK` which means the process has finished. Does this means that I am doing something wrong in my route?

What is the right way of fixing this? Interceptor? Setting a Camel headers? Doing something in the route to say it's complete?

I am using Apache Camel 2.12.1 and PAYLOAD mode.

**EDIT**: It seems something related to OneWay endpoint. Is there any way to deactivate that?

**EDIT2:** After hours trying things I think I have the root cause. My WSDL is not defining any output for that particular operation. I cannot change the WSDL. That said, I believe that when CXF is using the WSDL for creating the endpoint it automatically assumes it is a OneWay endpoint since there is no output. That means the response is sent back as soon as we get the request with code 202. Also, I believe there is no possible OutInteceptor chain because of this reason. Personally I believe it's ok to send back 202 but it is a service requirement to send back 200. Is there any configuration I change in CXF to set that in OneWay endpoint mode?

Comment: One way operations would make sense to return 202 [although 200 is possible too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/EAI2/EAI2_WebServices6.html). [CXF maintains an interceptor that sends a 202 straight after the read phase](http://cxf.547215.n5.nabble.com/OneWay-interpretation-and-HTTP-binding-td5711719.html) - you could probably intercept a 202 response [similar to this approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7575970/how-can-i-prevent-apache-cxf-from-sending-a-response-message) or [this suggestion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976369/intercept-http-response-with-cxf)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So I have been trying the different possibilities here but no luck. I am gonna edit my post to provide more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, we found an interceptor for doing that:

```
public class SoapResponseInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public SoapResponseInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        message.getExchange().setOneWay(false);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!